# How to get black text color on .net maui menubar

Tags: .net, maui

I am trying to use a MenuBar in .NET MAUI but the text of the MenuBarItem's are showing as white and I can't seem to change them.  Anyone know why they are white or how to change them?

XAML below:

```
<Shell
x:Class="SnapSignalTel.AppShell"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SnapSignalTel"
Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled"
Shell.NavBarIsVisible="True"
Title="{Binding TitleText}"
BackgroundColor="#FFF2F2F2"
>
<Shell.BindingContext>
    <local:MainViewModel />
</Shell.BindingContext>
<Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
    <BackButtonBehavior IsVisible="False" />
</Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
<Shell.MenuBarItems>
    <MenuBarItem Text="File" >
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Load" />
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Save" />
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Exit" />
    </MenuBarItem>
    <MenuBarItem Text="Modes">
    </MenuBarItem>
    <MenuBarItem Text="Help">
    </MenuBarItem>
</Shell.MenuBarItems>

<ShellContent
    Title=""
    ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
    Route="MainPage" />
```

The screenshot below shows the toplevel items white (these are the MenuBarItem's).  The drop down items are black text though (these are MenuFlyoutItem's)? Weird and can't seem to change them.

[image]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you tried using a custom menubar control?

Comment: I have tried customizing with exposed XAML attributes but there wasn't anything that would affect the font color.  Do you mean creating a menubar of my own?  Do you have example code or something on the internet you could point me to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received and answer on another platform for this same question.  Using a Style as below worked.

```
<Shell.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="Stylenamehere" TargetType="Element">
        <Setter Property="Shell.BackgroundColor" Value="#FFF2F2F2" />
        <Setter Property="Shell.TitleColor" Value="Black" />
    </Style>
</Shell.Resources>
```

The above Style is put in the xaml above (in my original post) just below the <Shell ...> tag (so just before the BindingContext tag).

```
    <ShellContent
    Title=""
    Style="{StaticResource Stylenamehere}"
    ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
    Route="MainPage" />
```

Then in the <ShellContent... > tag, add the Style as above.

This then allowed me to change the Text of the menu items using "Shell.TitleColor"

I also removed the (BackgroundColor="#FFF2F2F2") attribute in the XAML in the original post (last item in the <Shell ...> tag).

So it now looks like this:

```
<Shell
x:Class="SnapSignalTel.AppShell"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SnapSignalTel"
Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled"
Shell.NavBarIsVisible="True"
Title="{Binding TitleText}">
<Shell.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="SomeStyleName" TargetType="Element">
        <Setter Property="Shell.BackgroundColor" Value="#FFF2F2F2" />
        <Setter Property="Shell.TitleColor" Value="Black" />
    </Style>
</Shell.Resources>
<Shell.BindingContext>
    <local:MainViewModel />
</Shell.BindingContext>
<Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
    <BackButtonBehavior IsVisible="False" />
</Shell.BackButtonBehavior>

<Shell.MenuBarItems>
    <MenuBarItem Text="File" >
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Load" />
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Save" />
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Exit" />
    </MenuBarItem>
    <MenuBarItem Text="Modes">
    </MenuBarItem>
    <MenuBarItem Text="Help">
    </MenuBarItem>
</Shell.MenuBarItems>

<ShellContent
    Title=""
    Style="{StaticResource SomeStyleName}"
    ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
    Route="MainPage" />

</Shell>
```